# How to execute query on hive with jinjasql

Tags: python, hive, jinja2, sql-injection, pyhive

Is it possible to execute query for hive using jinjasql and pyhive?
When I tried it I got following error.

```
pyhive.exc.ProgrammingError: Unsupported param format: 
odict_values(['XXXXXXX'])
```

I can execute query with jinjasql as well as with pyhive but I need to use both together to prevent sql injection.

Environment (all on the same VM.)

- [Hortonworks Data Platform (HDP®) 2.6.4 on Hortonworks Sandbox for
  VirtualBox](https://jp.hortonworks.com/downloads/#sandbox)
- [Jinjasql](https://github.com/hashedin/jinjasql) 0.1.6
- [PyHive](https://github.com/dropbox/PyHive/blob/master/pyhive/common.py) 0.5.1
- Python 3.5.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pyhive supports list, tuple and dict in params. While jinjasql supports multiple param style, and as mentioned in the documentation [here](https://github.com/hashedin/jinjasql#multiple-param-styles)

It should return a list, except for 'named' or 'pyformat' which would return a dictionary. Since Jinjasql creates a Ordereddict it is throwing this exception. Solution should be to use a param style which returns a list.

Hope this helps :)

UPDATE for python 3:
In python 3 you will have to convert the parameters to list as dict.values() returns a [view](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict-views) of the dictionary values.

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned that PyHive allows list for execute parameter I used list function following your suggestion to convet bind_params to a list.

```
from pyhive import hive
from jinjasql import JinjaSql
j = JinjaSql()

template = "SELECT * FROM sample_07 WHERE code = {{ codex }}"
data = {'codex': '13-1061'}

query, bind_params = j.prepare_query(template, data)
updated_bind_params = list(bind_params)

cursor = hive.connect('sandbox.hortonworks.com').cursor()
cursor.execute(query, updated_bind_params)
print(cursor.fetchall())
```

It can fetch record from hive.